# Google map GLatLng equivalent in Bing

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I have this google map line of code that I need to find the equivalent in  Bing map

```
sb.Append("map.addOverlay(createMarker(new GLatLng(" + dataRow[7].ToString() + "," + dataRow[8].ToString() + "),");
```

I guess the **new GLatLng** takes these two values of (datarow 7 and datarow 8) and convert them to xy values as seen below:

```
 Ba: -78.624148
    x: -78.624148
    Xd: 35.727867
    y: 35.727867
```

How do I take two two values and convert them to XY values in use them with Bing Pushpin since I can't use GLatLng withg Bing.

Note: I am converting our map from google to Bing.

Answer (score 1):

Bing Maps uses Microsoft.Maps.Location to represent a coordinate. Here is a simple example of how to add a pushpin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Add default pushpin</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = null;

      function getMap()
      {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'});
      }

      function addDefaultPushpin()
      {
        var pushpin= new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), null); 
        map.entities.push(pushpin);
      }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="getMap();">
      <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
      <div>
         <input type="button" value="AddDefaultPushpin" onclick="addDefaultPushpin();" />
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can find full documentation on Bing Maps here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx